# How to replace Single Quotation Mark with two Quotation Mark

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string that contains single quotation mark `'`
i want to replace it with two Quotation mark `''`

i tried in `str.Replace(''','''')` but throws an error

How to replce it?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah. Likely because you have a really simple simple trivial syntax error. It likely gets really clear once you READ the error message. WHich you do not even paste here. HInt: str.Replace("'", "''") - in C# strings start and end with a ", not with a '.

Comment: If this is for SQL a parametrized query will do that automagically for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
str.Replace("'", "''");
```

Use double quotes to surround your single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace(string oldValue, string newValue) overload of string class.

```
str = str.Replace("'","''")
```

Comment: This would `bob's` -> `bob"s`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. changing my answer.